# Select pay rate based on day and shift start time

Tags: excel

Im creating an excel pay sheet so i can keep tabs on my pay.

I have two pay rates,

£9.30 is paid for hours worked from 6pm to 8am Monday to Thursday
£10.30 is paid for hours worked from 6pm Friday to 8am Monday.

I have a column that displays the pay rate, i want this to populate automatically with excel looking at the day of the week and then the start time and then returning the correct pay rate.

For example,

If the day is a Mon and the start time is 6pm return £9.30
If the day is Fri and the start time is 6pm return £10.30 etc etc

Any one have any ideas on how i can achieve this? Id rather this be formula based instead of VBA if possible but if it cant be formula based then VBA it is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: we will need screenshots of your excel and what have you tried so far

Comment: You can set up a lookup table, and use the lookup formulas built into Excel. By the way, this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ron, Thanks for the comment, didnt help at all. Besides i find your reply somewhat rude. Did you even stop to think that im new to Excel? Or stop and think im new to using this place? Also to clarify, im trying to develop a spreadsheet and as such dont have ANYTHING to provide to you hence why i asked the question. If this isnt a free service then why am i not paying for it? The problem with places like this is people like you believing they are bigger and better than every one else. Get off of your horse before your knocked off it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a few assumptions because your question was unclear about the possible start times for your shifts. Your wording and examples lead me to believe that your shifts always begin at 6 PM regardless of the day. I created a possible solution or start to a solution based on that assumption that does not rely on VBA. I've included links to an excel workbook with my solution and a screen shot. (I'm only allowed 2 links with my current rep.)

As Gowtham Shiva suggested in the comments, a screen shot of what you have so far would be helpful.

I created two tables and a named ranged called “valDays”. To use the workbook, you enter the date and start time for your shift in tblPay. Enter the pay rate for a specific day and time in tblRates. valDays provides a way to convert the text for a day of the week into a number for calculating date/time serial numbers.

Feel free to comment/message me for clarification. I’ll do my best to reply and refine the solution as necessary. I hope you find this answer helpful and appreciate feedback. This is my first time providing an answer on Stack Overflow.

I’m going to assume you know how to name a range, create tables, and rename tables in excel. If you don’t there are plenty of YouTubers and bloggers that cover these topics quite well.
List the days in a column off to the right. (I used column K.) “Sun”, “Mon”, “Tue”, etc. Select all the cells with the days of the week and name the range “valDays”.

Formula in tblRates[Serial]: 
    “=MATCH(tblRates[[#This Row],[Day]],valDays,0)+tblRates[[#This Row],[Time]]”

Formula in tblPay[Serial]:
    “=WEEKDAY([Date])+[StartTime]”

Formula in tblPay[Rate]:
    “=INDEX(tblRates[Rate],MATCH([Serial],tblRates[Serial],0))”

You can download the excel document and view these screenshots of a possible solution.

[Link to Excel Workbook on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-r_ImyJFQdIbjdCOWZXLWdUUnc/view?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxnTM.jpg)

Comment: YOU ABSOLUTE GENIUS! Thank you so very very much for this. Youve just solved a massive headache literally. Truly grateful.